# How to stop Google from recognizing me?

Tags: gmail

I've done everything to make myself anonymous but Google still recognizes me.

What I am trying to do is create multiple Gmail accounts. I can only create one account and if I try second time, it asks me to verify mobile number, which I cannot skip.

Now, I have tried using VPN (on various servers) and clearing all browser data. So, to Gmail I should be a new user everytime I do this and it shouldn't ask for my phone number (it doesn't ask for the first time). What happens instead is Google always knows that I've already created an account and asks me to verify my mobile number.

What methods do Google use to track me? Is there a way out of this?

Comment: Are you sure they aren't just detecting the VPN and asking for proof you are real?

Answer (score 2):

This behaivor is not them recognizing you (they may or may not be doing it) but new policy from google that you have to have a phone number for creating any new account. Basically you cannot hide from this because is their service and they make the rules for using it.

If you are need the accounts for testing or any other use that doesn't need privacy you could use yopmail.com or maildrop.cc (the later is opensource and you can even mount it on-site) both are faster than creating gmail account but offer no privacy (you don't even have a password and anyone can access the inbox)

If you need privacy for your account you could use other services (https://prism-break.org/en/categories/gnu-linux/#email-accounts, cock.li) or even set up your own server: https://prism-break.org/en/categories/gnu-linux/#mail-servers(if you have the technical attitudes and love to learn)

Comment: But on every new device I can create an account without phone number - it can be skipped.